unable to login via putty ssh to my ec2 linux instance in aws : no supported authentication methods available
i am new in aws,
i created two linux instances : amazon linux and ubuntu linux
I downloaded RSA ppk key pairs + imported to putty, however I am unable to login via putty,
i get this error
no supported authentication methods available;

when I logged via web console to amazon  linux, i wass surpised that there is no auth.log

so I checked on ubuntu and I found this logs:


Apr  3 06:19:36 ip sshd[11329]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
Apr  3 06:19:38 ip sshd[11329]: Connection closed by authenticating user ubuntu port 4798 [preauth]

Any idea


how old is your version of PuTTY? 2) have you tried searching this website (or the web in general) for the option mentioned in the 1st line of your logs?


putty attempts SHA-1 which often gets denied until version 0.75 (current is .80). See the answer(s) here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/759835/247007

you are right, I had old ver. putty, pls mark it answer.
